# How to fetch existing cache data on every input change and non-existing data with submit button?

Tags: reactjs, caching, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-query

My application has a user `input` an `id` to send as a `request` and the `response data` that matches that `id` is rendered.

If the `data` already exist in the `cache`, I'd like the application to fetch from the `cache` on each `input change` while the `submit button` is disabled.

If the `data` does not exist in the `cache`, the application can only send the `request` by having the user click the enabled `submit button`.

I'm using `queryClient.getQueryData` as suggested to get data from `cache` for a specific `queryKey`. If `queryClient.getQueryData` is `truthy`, I'd grab data from cache on every input change, else the  `submit button` is  `enabled` for the user to fetch manually.

Update: Thanks to @TkDodo for solving `If the data already exist in the cache, I'd like the application to fetch from the cache on each input change while the submit button is disabled.` by adding `useQuery` options `staleTime` and `cacheTime` with an appropriate value.

Possible Solution: To solve `If the data does not exist in the cache, the application can only send the request by having the user click the enabled submit button.` We `disable` the `query` if `getQueryData` for that entry returns `undefined`, and then call `refetch()` when the button is clicked.

Attempt: I've defined `characterData = queryClient.getQueryData(["rickandmorty", idQuery])` and `charBool = characterData ? true : false`. We're checking if the `query` exist in the `cache`, if so return `true` otherwise `false`. We then pass that value to `useQuery`'s `enabled` option. However, `characterData` always initially logs as `undefined` when `handleRickAndMortyFetch` is triggered, therefore logs `charBool` as `false`, resulting in the `useQuery`'s `enabled` option not being passed the desired `truthy` value.

To double check is characterData is always returning undefined, I created a separate handler just for logging purposes. So `handleSingleLogCache` logs `characterData` and it returns the data! Therefore `charBool` returns `true`. Why is that happening?

How do I get `getQueryData` to not initially return `undefined` so that `charBool` returns `true`, resulting in useQuery's enabled option to be passed that `truthy` value. I appreciate the help!

Here is a snippet of the related code.
My code: https://codesandbox.io/s/rick-and-morty-fetch-nonexisting-cache-2gy8r
Desired demo: https://epic-react-exercises.vercel.app/react/advanced-hooks/2

```
    <Home/>
    const characterData = queryClient.getQueryData(["rickandmorty", idQuery]);
    const charBool = characterData ? true : false;

    const handleSingleLogCache = () => {
      console.log(characterData) // returns data
      console.log(charBool) // returns true
     }
    
    const handleRickAndMortyFetch = () => {
        return delay()
          .then(() => axios(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${idQuery}`))
          .then((res) => res.data);
    };

    const { data, error, isLoading } = useQuery(
      ["rickandmorty", idQuery],
      handleRickAndMortyFetch,
      {
        cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        enabled: false || idQuery !== 0 || charBool,
        staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
      }
    );
    
    const handleFetchOnInputChange = (event) => {
      console.log(characterData);
      console.log(charBool);
      setIdQuery(event.target.value, () => {
        handleRickAndMortyFetch();
      });
    };

    <button onClick={handleSingleLogCache}>Single Cache Log</button>
    
    // <SearchForm/>  
    const disable =
    isLoading || parseFloat(formId) === idQuery || !idQuery || cachedCharacters;
        
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSubmitForm)}>
      <input onChange={handleFetchOnInputChange} />
      <button disabled={disable}>Search Character</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried writing the cache? Also -- it sounds like a button click and text change are fundementally different behaviors. You shouldn't try to stuff both into the same function.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Sorry, could you explain what you mean by writing the cache?

Comment: You mention a cache, where is it?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev React-Query handles the `cache`. If you type an input `id` and click on `Log cache from last request`, you'll see the `cache data`. The logging cache code is located in `<SearchForm/>`. To check if I have an individual item exist in cache, I have `const characterData = queryClient.getQueryData(["rickandmorty", idQuery])` located in `<Home/>`

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev you forgot to wrap this into functions https://codesandbox.io/s/rick-and-morty-fetch-nonexisting-cache-2gy8r?file=/src/components/Home/Home.jsx:1568-1693

Comment: @DmitriyMozgovoy Could you please explain what you did?

Answer (score 0):

> If the data already exist in the cache, I'd like the application to fetch from the cache on each input change while the submit button is disabled.

for this, you'd need to mark your queries as `stale` with an appropriate `staleTime`, and also maybe set a higher `cacheTime` to avoid garbage collection. If a stale query is mounted, a background fetch is happening, which it looks like you don't want. As long as queries are `fresh`, data will always only be taken from the cache.

> If the data does not exist in the cache, the application can only send the request by having the user click the enabled submit button.

I'd disable the query if `getQueryData` for that entry returns `undefined`, and then call  `refetch()` when the button is clicked. That should put data in the cache and then in turn enable the query. Disabling the button is basically the opposite

Comment: Thank you for your help! I added `cacheTime` and `staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24`, and now the app only fetches if `non-existing` in `cache` and takes from `cache` if `existing`. Great!

Comment: Now to `disable` the query if `getQueryData` for that entry returns `undefined`, I’ve defined `const charBool = characterData ? true : false`. Then, `useQuery( .. {enabled: false || idQuery !== 0 || charBool})`. However, `characterData` always returns `undefined` when I log `characterData`. I checked if a stable `queryClient` in `QueryClientProvider` is set and also if my `query key` is correct. They’re both correct, but it still returns `undefined`. Kindly suggest?

Comment: I'd need to see that in a codesandbox please, hard to say otherwise :)

Comment: Here you go! `https://codesandbox.io/s/rick-and-morty-fetch-nonexisting-cache-2gy8r`. `<Home />` holds the `characterData` and `charBool` code and they're also being logged on every input change in `handleFetchOnInputChange`, which return `undefined` and `false`. `<SearchForm />` holds the `disable` condition. Please take a look. I appreciate it!

Comment: there's just a flaw in your boolean logic, combining things with or (`||`) will yield `true` if any of the parts is true. what you want is: `enabled: idQuery !== 0 && charBool`. Then there is one more issue that your idQuery is sometimes a string, and sometimes a number. you can clearly see this in the react-query-devtools that there are two entries for the same id. good luck.

Comment: Thank you, @TkDodo. I've solved the `idQuery` returning a `string`. It now always returns an `integer`. I've now attempting to solve `characterData` initially returning `undefined`, which gets `charBool` to return `false`, resulting in `useQuery`'s `enabled` option to not work as desired. I've started a bounty if you're interested!

Comment: @TkDodo what if you set a high stale/cacheTime BUT want to override it when a certain action happens like "add new item, so get the new data"....so you want to then ignore the stale/cache time and get new data. Do you initiate a refetch OR ?

Comment: you call `queryClient.invalidateQueries('key')` with your queryKey, which will manually mark the query as stale and refetch it if it's active.